# Problema com link em Wordpress com page-nomeDaPage

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Criei post_types para a área Administrativa em function.php:

```
// Meus posts types
function meus_posts_type() {
    // Testemunhos
    register_post_type('testemunhos',
        array(
            'labels'    => array(

                'name'  => __('Testemunhos'),
                'singular_name'     => __('Testemunhos')
            ),
            'public'        => true, 
            'has_archive'   => true, 
            'menu_icon'     => 'dashicons-format-chat',
            'supports'      => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes'),

        )    
        );

        register_post_type('consultoria',
        array(
            'labels'    => array(

                'name'  => __('Consultorias'),
                'singular_name'     => __('Consultorias')
            ),
            'public'        => true, 
            'has_archive'   => true, 
            'menu_icon'     => 'dashicons-clipboard',
            'supports'      => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes'),

        )    
        );

        register_post_type('treinamentos',
        array(
            'labels'    => array(

                'name'  => __('Treinamentos'),
                'singular_name'     => __('Treinamentos')
            ),
            'public'        => true, 
            'has_archive'   => true, 
            'menu_icon'     => 'dashicons-welcome-learn-more',
            'supports'      => array('title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes'),

        )    
        );

        register_post_type('clientes',
        array(
            'labels'    => array(

                'name'  => __('Clientes'),
                'singular_name'     => __('Clientes')
            ),
            'public'        => true, 
            'has_archive'   => true, 
            'menu_icon'     => 'dashicons-admin-multisite',
            'supports'      => array('title', 'thumbnail', 'page-attributes'),

        )    
        );
}

add_action( 'init', 'meus_posts_type' );
```

Também Criei 2 page: page-consultorias.php e page-treinamentos.php.

No meu menu, que não é dinâmico, coloquei os links desta forma:

```
<section class="menu cid-rlhN7gSbPQ" once="menu" id="menu2-0">


    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand beta-menu navbar-dropdown align-items-center navbar-fixed-top navbar-toggleable-sm">
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <div class="hamburger">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </div>
        </button>
        <div class="menu-logo">
            <div class="navbar-brand">
                <span class="navbar-logo">
                    <a href="<?php bloginfo('url');?>">
                        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/assets/images/residuo-de-valor-logo-principal-232x123.png" alt="Mobirise" title="" style="height: 8rem;">
                    </a>
                </span>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav nav-dropdown" data-app-modern-menu="true">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link link text-black display-4" href="<?php bloginfo('url');?>">Início</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown open"><a class="nav-link link text-black dropdown-toggle display-4" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown-submenu" aria-expanded="true">Nossos Serviços</a><div class="dropdown-menu"><a class="text-black dropdown-item display-4" href="consultorias">Consultoria</a><a class="text-black dropdown-item display-4" href="treinamentos" aria-expanded="false">Workshops e Treinamentos</a></div></li><li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link link text-black display-4" href="#">Blog</a></li><li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link link text-black display-4" href="sobre">Sobre</a></li></ul>
            <div class="navbar-buttons mbr-section-btn"><a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary display-4" href="index.html#form1-4">
                    <span class="btn-icon mbri-mobile mbr-iconfont mbr-iconfont-btn">
                    </span>Fale com um Consultor</a></div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</section>
```

Onde este trecho específico do menu:

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown open"><a class="nav-link link text-black dropdown-toggle display-4" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown-submenu" aria-expanded="true">Nossos Serviços</a><div class="dropdown-menu"><a class="text-black dropdown-item display-4" href="consultorias">Consultoria</a><a class="text-black dropdown-item display-4" href="treinamentos" aria-expanded="false">Workshops e Treinamentos</a></div></li>
```

Coloco no `href="consultorias"` e `href="treinamentos"`.

**Mas os links não estão funcionando.**

Minhas duas páginas referidas estão desta forma:

**page-consultorias.php**

```
<?php 

get_header(); 

/*
    Template name: Consultoria
*/

?>


<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

<section class="features18 popup-btn-cards cid-rlWjfrLtP9" id="features18-u">



<div class="container">
    <h2 class="mbr-section-title pb-3 align-center mbr-fonts-style display-2"><strong>SOLUÇÕES CONSULTORIA</strong></h2>
    <h3 class="mbr-section-subtitle display-5 align-center mbr-fonts-style mbr-light"><strong>GOVERNOS | EMPRESAS | ONGs
</strong><div>Consultoria especializada em gestão integrada de resíduos sólidos 
</div><div><br></div></h3>

<?php query_posts( 'post_type=consultoria' ); ?>

       <?php if(have_posts()): while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>

       <div class="media-container-row pt-5 ">
        <div class="card p-3 col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="card-wrapper ">
                <div class="card-img">
                    <div class="mbr-overlay"></div>
                    <div class="mbr-section-btn text-center">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-primary display-4">Saiba Mais</a>
                    </div>
                    <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('thumbnail'); ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="card-box">
                    <h4 class="card-title mbr-fonts-style display-7">
                    <b><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title_attribute(); ?></a></b>
                    </h4>
                    <p class="mbr-text mbr-fonts-style align-left display-7">
                    <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

       <?php endwhile; ?>

       <?php else : ?>
           <h1>Não há nenhuma consultoria ainda cadastrada.</h1>

       <?php endif; ?>

   <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>



    </div>
</div>
</section>


<br/><br/><br/><br/>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**E page-treinamentos.php**

```
<?php 

get_header(); 

/*
    Template name: Treinamentos
*/

?>


<br/><br/><br/><br/>

<section class="features18 popup-btn-cards cid-rlWkB2eQKv" id="features18-y">




    <div class="container">
        <h2 class="mbr-section-title pb-3 align-center mbr-fonts-style display-2"><strong>WORKSHOPS E TREINAMENTOS</strong></h2>
        <h3 class="mbr-section-subtitle display-5 align-center mbr-fonts-style mbr-light"><strong>GOVERNOS | EMPRESAS | ONGs (IN-COMPANY
)</strong><div>Workshops e treinamentos especializados em gestão integrada de resíduos sólidos
</div><div><br></div></h3>

<?php query_posts( 'post_type=treinamentos' ); ?>

       <?php if(have_posts()): while(have_posts()): the_post(); ?>

       <div class="media-container-row pt-5 ">
            <div class="card p-3 col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                <div class="card-wrapper ">
                    <div class="card-img">
                        <div class="mbr-overlay"></div>
                        <div class="mbr-section-btn text-center">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="btn btn-primary display-4">Saiba Mais</a>
                        </div>
                        <img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('thumbnail'); ?>">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-box">
                        <h4 class="card-title mbr-fonts-style display-7">
                            <b><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title_attribute(); ?></a></b>
                        </h4>
                        <b>Tipo: </b><?php the_field('tipo'); ?>
                        <p class="mbr-text mbr-fonts-style align-left display-7">
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

       <?php endwhile; ?>

       <?php else : ?>
           <h2>Não há Workshops e Treinamentos cadastrados...</h2>

       <?php endif; ?>

   <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>






        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<br/><br/><br/><br/>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**O problema é que quando clico nos links eles ficam sempre na página inicial.**

E não estou entendo, porque funcionou em um primeiro momento, depois simplesmente parou de funcionar.

Comment: Era um erro na criação das páginas dentro do Wordpress que estavam com links errados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Da área administrativa, tem os "Modelos de Paginas".

Quando coloca:

```
  /*
    Template name: Fale com um Consultor
*/
```

Este nome é apresentado. Basta definir na página o modelo.